# awk is not printing value for count and sum

Tags: awk

file as

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Code:

```
awk -F '' 'BEGIN{sum=0;count=0;min=100;max=0} {if($1<min){min=$1}; if(max>$1) {max=$1}; sum=sum+$1;count=count+1; print "count=" $count  " sum="$sum " min="  $min " max=" $max} END {avg=sum/count; print "Min="$min " max="$max " avg="$avg }' Accnotodb.txt
```

its not returning any value for count and sum
 Please check and help me

Comment: You are referencing variable with dollars, i.e `$sum`. `$` is used to reference fields. Just use the variable name on its own and it will work. Also you don't need to initialise variables, they all start at 0 the first time they are referenced.

Comment: Also i rewrote your script `awk -F '' '$1<min||!min{min=$1}max>$1||!max{max=$1}{sum+=$1;count+=1;print "count="count" sum="sum" min="min" max="max} END {avg=sum/count;print "Min="min" max="max" avg="avg }'`

Answer (score 3):

```
END {avg=sum/count; print "Min="$min " max="$max " avg="$avg }
```

IN awk, the `$` is an **operator** to access the value of the field named by the next expression, For example `$1`, `$0`, `$NF`

You need to remove the `$`

```
END {avg=sum/count; print "Min="min " max="max " avg="avg }
```

You can write your program like this:

```
awk '
    NR == 1 {max = min = $1}
    $1 < min {min = $1}
    $1 > max {max = $1}
    {sum += $1}
    END {
        if (NR == 0) 
            print "no data"
        else 
            print "min=" min " max=" max " avg=" sum/NR
    }
'
```

Comment: And you need to write `avg=(count?sum/count:0)` or similar to avoid a core dump on empty files.

Comment: Thank you now i can see avg is printing  but still min and max values  remains same                                                                                                     awk -F '' 'BEGIN{sum=0;count=0;min=100;max=0} {if($1<min){min=$1}; if(max>$1){max=$1}; sum=sum+$1;count=count+1; print "count="count  " sum="sum " min=" $min " max=" $max} END {avg=sum/count; print "Min="$min " max="$max " avg="$avg }' Accnotodb.txt

Comment: And, as I learned recently from Ed Morton, it is best to initialize min and max with real data instead of arbitrary numbers (100 and 0) which may be insufficient

Comment: oops, that's embarrassing. I already check for empty file though.